# Ajax NumericUpDownExtender Button Layout

Tags: .net, css, ajax

I am trying to set up an age text box with a Numeric Up Down extender. This should be simple:

But when the page is displayed (At least in IE 8) the up down buttons have a lot of vertical space between them (The bottom of the up button is aligned almost with the top of the text box and the top of the down button is aligned almost with the bottom of the text box). I don't seem to be able to find anything about aligning these buttons if you use the default buttons.

Comment: People are a lot more willing to help out when you accept answers.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem, I tried everything but could not resolve it.
I was surprised when it resolved by just replacing doctype with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

If up and down buttons are image button than try to align them middle.

Comment: I am not using specified buttons, just the default buttons.